# Dotnet SDK - Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net, .net

Hace poco comencé a incursionar en el mundo de .net, y normalmente uso visual studio, pero no me siento cómodo al 100% ya que me gusta mas trabajar en visual studio code, se que se pueden crear proyectos instalando el sdk de dotnet en mi pc, y crearlo por medio de comandos tipo dotnet new apiweb -o name, y hasta ahi todo bien, el problema es cuando quiero pasarle el proyecto a un amigo y el no maneja visual studio code, no encuentro como hacerlo funcionar en visual studio, puedo abrir el proyecto y todo, le agregue un .snl y nada, si alguien me pudiera guiar en esta parte, estaria muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Sin saber que tiene el proyecto, dificil saber porque no puede ejecutarlo. Son intercambiables, o sea deberias poder en las dos ide sin problemas...

Comment: Por ejemplo que errores tenes al pasar un proyecto en particular y que tiene?